# checkbox icone google no firefox

Tags: html, css

Estou tendo um problema com um `checkbox` no firefox.

Montei ele assim:

```css
.checkbox { 
        display:none; 
    } 
    .checkbox + label:before {
        font-family: 'Material Icons';
        display: inline-block;
        color: #0091FF;
        transform: scale(2.1);
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .checkbox + label:before { 
        content: "check_box_outline_blank"; 
    }
    .checkbox + label:before { 
        letter-spacing: 8px; 
    } 
    .checkbox:checked + label:before { 
        content: "check_box"; 
    }
```

```html
<!-- Material Icons (Google) -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1' class='checkbox' name='checkbox1'><label for='checkbox1'></label>
```

Ele esta funcionando no Chrome, Safari. Mas no FireFox não. Alguém sabe o motivo?

Comment: Retira isso do CSS `letter-spacing: 8px;`

Comment: deu certo, posta a resposta para eu marcar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retire o `letter-spacing: 8px` do CSS que irá resolver.

Veja a necessidade desse estilo, caso precise, terá que pesquisar o porque do Firefox ter esse problema.